# Compare values in different csv files and join based on the value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to compare file#1 to file#2 based on a'Sentences' column that exists with the same name in both files. If a match is found a value in file#2, then the corresponding value in 'description' column will be copied from file#2 to file#1. I have found few related questions here, but I wasn't able to get them to do what I wanted. My code is shown below.

Input:

File#1:

| Description | Sentences |
| --- | --- |
|  | Hello world |
|  | Hi there |

File#2:

| Description | Sentences |
| --- | --- |
| text1 | Hello world |
| text2 | Hi |
| text3 | Hello |
| text4 | Hi there |
| text5 | Welcome |

Output:
File#3:

| Description | Sentences |
| --- | --- |
| text1 | Hello world |
| text4 | Hi there |

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data_sample = pd.read_csv (r'1.csv')   
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data_sample, columns= ['Sentences'])

data_all = pd.read_csv (r'2.csv')   #read the csv file (put 'r' before the path string to address any special characters in the path, such as '\'). Don't forget to put the file name at the end of the path + ".csv"
df_all= pd.DataFrame(data_all, columns= ['Sentences'])

df_sample['Sentences'].equals(df_all['Sentences'])
print (df_sample['Sentences'].equals(df_all['Sentences']))

for i in df_sample.iterrows():
    for j in df_all.iterrows():
        if (j <> ""):
            if (i==j):
                print(i, j)
```

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you provide a minimal reproducible problem set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the example. What you have provided falls short of this goal. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: Thank you. Updated accordingly.